# Eclipse suspends my process in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, linked-list

So I am working on a project involving Linked Lists. We have to make the Nodes and the Linked Lists ourselves (not allowed to use the Java provided ones). As part of the project, I am making a list that will automatically adjust itself upon certain criteria (when the word being entered is the same as one that already exists, move that Node to the front of the list). My code appears to run fine but after a certain amount of time, it just stops running. When I try debugging it, Eclipse just suspends the process at that point and I cannot figure out why as it provides absolutely no feedback at all. It appears to be on one of the while loops but I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is relatively long so I will paste it below this wall of text. I am not super experienced in programming yet so you might notice some mistakes/annoyances.

SelfAdjustingListOne.java

```
public class SelfAdjustingListOne extends UnsortedList
{
    public SelfAdjustingListOne()
    {
        super();
    }

    public SelfAdjustingListOne(long timer)
    {
        super(timer);
    }

    public void adjustingAdd(Node input)
    {
        // If there's nothing in the list, make this the first and last node
        if (getFront() == null)
        {
            setFront(input);
            setBack(input);
            input.setIndex(0);
        } else if (sameWord(input) != null)
        {
            // If the word already exists, increment the word count and send that node to
            // the front of the list
            Node sameString = sameWord(input), current = getFront(), previous;
            try
            {
                // Will return null if sameString is the first node on the list
                previous = getByIndex(sameString.getIndex() - 1);
            } catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                previous = null;
            }
            // If sameString is the first node, no link needs to be set
            if (previous != null)
                previous.setLink(sameString.getLink());
            // Link the node we are moving to the front node
            sameString.setLink(getFront());
            // Set the value of the front node to the node we are moving
            setFront(sameString);
            // Increment its count
            sameString.plusCount();
            // While the current node exists and has not surpassed the previous location of
            // the node we moved, increment the index value of each node by 1
            while (current != null && current.getIndex() != sameString.getIndex())
            {
                current.plusIndex();
                current = current.getLink();
            }
            // Set the new front node's index to 0 (Beginning of the list)
            sameString.setIndex(0);
            plusComparisons();
            plusComparisons();
        } else
        {
            // If the list has at least one node and the word being added doesn't exist, add
            // this node to the front of the list
            input.setLink(getFront());
            Node current = getFront();
            while (current != null)
            {
                current.plusIndex();
                current = current.getLink();
            }
            setFront(input);
            input.setIndex(0);
            plusComparisons();
            plusNodeChanges();
            plusNodeChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

UnsortedList.java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class UnsortedList
{
    private Node front;
    private Node back;
    private Long timer;
    private int numOfComparisons;
    private int nodeChanges;

    public UnsortedList()
    {

    }

    public UnsortedList(long timer)
    {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    public void addBack(Node input)
    {
        if (front == null)
        {
            setFront(input);
            setBack(input);
            input.setIndex(0);
        } else if (sameWord(input) != null)
        {
            Node sameString = sameWord(input);
            sameString.plusCount();
            numOfComparisons += 2;
        } else
        {
            getBack().setLink(input);
            input.setIndex(back.getIndex() + 1);
            setBack(input);
            numOfComparisons++;
            nodeChanges += 2;
        }
    }

    public void addFront(Node input)
    {
        if (front == null)
        {
            setFront(input);
            setBack(input);
            input.setIndex(0);
        } else if (sameWord(input) != null)
        {
            Node sameString = sameWord(input);
            sameString.plusCount();
            numOfComparisons += 2;
        } else
        {
            input.setLink(front);
            Node current = front;
            while (current != null)
            {
                current.plusIndex();
                current = current.getLink();
            }
            setFront(input);
            input.setIndex(0);
            numOfComparisons++;
            nodeChanges += 2;
        }
    }

    public void remove(int index)
    {
        Node current = front;
        do
        {
            if (current.getIndex() == index - 1)
            {
                if (current.getLink().getLink() != null)
                {
                    current.getLink().setIndex(-1);
                    current.setLink(current.getLink().getLink());
                    Node currentIndexNode = current.getLink();
                    while (currentIndexNode != null)
                    {
                        currentIndexNode.minusIndex();
                        currentIndexNode = currentIndexNode.getLink();
                    }
                } else
                {
                    current.getLink().setIndex(-1);
                    current.setLink(null);
                }
            }
            current = current.getLink();
        } while (!current.isEqual(back));
    }

    public void setFront(Node input)
    {
        front = input;
    }

    public void setBack(Node input)
    {
        back = input;
    }

    public Node getFront()
    {
        return front;
    }

    public Node getBack()
    {
        return back;
    }

    public Node getByIndex(int index) throws NullPointerException
    {
        Node current = front, currentIndexNode = current.getLink();
        while (current != null)
        {
            do
            {
                if (current.getIndex() == index)
                    return current;
                current = currentIndexNode;
                currentIndexNode = currentIndexNode.getLink();
            } while (currentIndexNode != null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Node getByWord(String word) throws NullPointerException
    {
        Node current = front, currentIndexNode = current.getLink();
        while (current != null)
        {
            do
            {
                if (current.getWord().equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                    return current;
                current = currentIndexNode;
                currentIndexNode = currentIndexNode.getLink();
            } while (currentIndexNode != null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int totalWords()
    {
        Node current = front;
        int totalWords = 0;
        while (current != null)
        {
            totalWords += current.getCount();
            current = current.getLink();
        }
        return totalWords;
    }

    public int totalUniqueWords()
    {
        Node current = front;
        int totalUniqueWords = 0;
        while (current != null)
        {
            totalUniqueWords++;
            current = current.getLink();
        }
        return totalUniqueWords;
    }

    public int totalNumOfComparisons()
    {
        return numOfComparisons;
    }

    public int totalNodeChanges()
    {
        return nodeChanges;
    }

    public String totalTimeElapsed()
    {
        if (timer == null)
            return "This is an untimed list";
        DecimalFormat threePlaces = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
        return threePlaces.format((System.nanoTime() - timer) * Math.pow(10, -9)) + " seconds";
    }

    public void plusComparisons()
    {
        numOfComparisons++;
    }

    public void plusNodeChanges()
    {
        nodeChanges++;
    }

    protected Node sameWord(Node input)
    {
        Node current = front;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.getWord().equalsIgnoreCase(input.getWord()))
                return current;
            current = current.getLink();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Node.java

```
public class Node
{
    private Node link;
    private String word;
    private int count = 1;
    private int index = -1;

    public Node(String word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public Node getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public void setLink(Node input)
    {
        link = input;
    }

    public void setWord(String input)
    {
        word = input;
    }

    public void setCount(int input)
    {
        count = input;
    }

    public void setIndex(int input)
    {
        index = input;
    }

    public void plusCount()
    {
        count++;
    }

    public void plusIndex()
    {
        index++;
    }

    public void minusIndex()
    {
        index--;
    }

    public boolean isEqual(Node input)
    {
        if (input.getWord().equalsIgnoreCase(this.word))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code which runs the SelfAdjustingListOne

```
public static SelfAdjustingListOne salo;
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Running fifth pass...");
        System.out.println("Time to execute fifth pass: " + pass5());
    }
public static String pass5()
    {
        salo = new SelfAdjustingListOne(System.nanoTime());
            try
            {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileDirectory + fileNames[0] + fileExtension));
                while (scanner.hasNext())
                {
                    String s = scanner.next();
                    s.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "");
                    s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$", "");
                    if (s.length() == 1 || s.length() == 0)
                    {
                        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(0)) && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)))
                            continue;
                    }
                    salo.adjustingAdd(new Node(s));
                }
                scanner.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("No file found matching that name/directory");
            }
        return salo.totalTimeElapsed();
    }
```

The file it says it's reading in is the A Bee Movie Script which I cannot post because of the max length of a post but any text file should do.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @samabcde I would be more than happy to provide an example but I am not quite sure why exactly this is happening. I could provide the rest of my files so the problem can be reproduced. Unfortunately, I cannot create a test case that creates this problem as I have no idea why it is happening and that is why I am here.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is happening without more details, try to add break point before the suspending code and run step by step to see what happen [you may reference this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html). And since you suspect the while loop is suspending, please post the related code also.

Comment: @samabcde I will try doing a breakpoint debug again in my spare time but that is where my problem originally rose from. Debugging is when Eclipse decides to suspend itself with no warning. If you are up to it, I posted all of the relevant code. Thanks for your interest and help so far.

Comment: Is class `Node` from library or custom class you made? I need this class to compile.

Comment: @samabcde My bad. I completely forgot to include that class. I have made an edit to include it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202278/discussion-between-samabcde-and-1poseidon3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with a little help from samabcde.

This block of code right here needed to be changed from this:

```
if (previous != null)
previous.setLink(sameString.getLink());
// Link the node we are moving to the front node
sameString.setLink(getFront());
// Set the value of the front node to the node we are moving
setFront(sameString);
```

To this:

```
if(sameString != getFront())
{
    sameString.setLink(getFront());
    // Set the value of the front node to the node we are moving
    setFront(sameString);
}
```

It was linking to itself because it never checked to see if the node it was setting the link of WAS ALREADY the first node in the list, therefore setting the link equal to itself.